# routes to news page - Will not show me the page

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

That's how I'm doing a news page and right now I have it like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("News", "News/{url}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "News",
            action = "Index",
            url = UrlParameter.Optional,
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
```

Now i have: www.helloworld.com/news/hello-world/123

i will have www.helloworld.com/hello-world/123

I also have this here for the common content

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "index",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

Error with:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, Int32)' in 'HelloWorld.Controllers.NewsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

```
routes.MapRoute("News", "{url}/{id}", new
            {
                controller = "News",
                action = "Index",
                url = UrlParameter.Optional,
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with this setup?

Comment: I have update @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: So you will think that I can only write {controller} before /url/id @TechGirl

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way for passing the values in a query string. First you need to create a `NewsContoller` after that yours URL will be www.helloworld.com/news/123 and you need to create an action method in your controller-

```
 public class NewsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Also you can refer the following link for further information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Please mark answer if you like it.

Comment: I know that. But that's not what my problem is, I know I want news and just have the url + id

Comment: You can use -www.helloworld.com/news/123 or www.helloworld.com/news?id=123

Comment: url must be a controller then it will work. Just like News controller